# $ git review git: 'review' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, github, version-control, gerrit, git-review

I am using git for source control in visual studio 2010. I can use commands like "git status" , "git commit" but when i try to use "git review" i am getting the error as " git: 'review' is not a git command. See 'git --help'."
Help me please

Edit1: i am using "git review" to submit git branches (code) to gerrit for review.

Answer (score 5):

`Git review` is an external command from `git`. It is not a command included in git code. You have to install it.

Please follow [Git-review documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/git-review) to the installation if you intend to use it.

Comment: I have followed the same, still no vain. any troubleshot steps to identify where the problem exactly present ?

Answer (score -3):

It means that `review` is not a valid command to be used with `git`.

For e.g. when you use `git add .` - git understands that you want to stage all the files that you have changed to be committed. `add .` is a valid commandment for git to do staging operation.

In similar fashion, `review` is not a valid command and thus git recommends you to lookout for help by running `git --help`

What do you intend to do with `review` command?

> EDIT 1: As per comments, adding screenshot of area from where pull
>   requests are created on github.com

[image: github screenshot for pull request]

Comment: this git review command is going to send my code for team-lead's review. i checked git --help, there is no review command in help list. P.S. i checked the git --help from other system, in that machine also it is not showing in help , BUT git review command is working fine there.

Comment: You have to send a pull request. If you repository is on github. go to your repository on browser and then you will see `Pull Request`. You need to create `pull request` for this. Let me know, if you need more explanation for pull request.

Comment: i am using gerrit. why i am using  "git review" is  to submit git branches to gerrit for review. The screen shot which you attached i never saw.

Comment: Its a different problem altogether then, not a git issue at all.